# Lowercase all text except xml tags

Tags: xml, linux, awk, sed

I've got a large number of tagged strings:

```
watch <TEAM>Philly's</TEAM> Game
what's on <TIME>Wednesday night eight o'clock</TIME>
```

I would like to lowercase all text except the XML tags. I.e.

```
watch <TEAM>philly's</TEAM> game
what's on <TIME>wednesday night eight o'clock</TIME>
```

I can lower case all the text by using awk:

```
awk '{print tolower($0)}' file.txt
```

but have no idea how to avoid XML tags. Any languages/tools are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this sed (gnu) one-liner may help:

```
sed -r 's/([^<>]*)($|<)/\L\1\E\2/g'
```

with your example:

```
kent$ echo "watch <TEAM>Philly's</TEAM> Game
what's on <TIME>Wednesday night eight o'clock</TIME>"|sed -r 's/([^<>]*)($|<)/\L\1\E\2/g' 
watch <TEAM>philly's</TEAM> game
what's on <TIME>wednesday night eight o'clock</TIME>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! My engineer's curiosity now asks how it works! Would you mind to explain the command? I see search/replace command with two capturing groups but don't see more..

Comment: @xeon change `\L\1\E\2` into `######\2` then you see what did the regex match. for `\L \E` please read info sed, there are detailed explanations.

Comment: `\E` is useless in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/' -e 's/\(<[^>]*>\)/\U\1/g' fileName
```

Comment: Looks like this solution just combines two commands (compared to the first answer). Why you use \U instead of \E?

Comment: @xeon, it is slightly different approach. The first expression converts everything to lowercase and the second one converts anything between < and > to uppercase. This might be handy in case currently not all xml tags are uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it with `awk`

```
awk -F"<|>" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s",(i%2?tolower($i):"<"$i">");print ""}' file
watch <TEAM>philly's</TEAM> game
what's on <TIME>wednesday night eight o'clock</TIME>
```

It separate fields by `<`or `>`, then loop trough the line one field at the time. 
If its even, change to lower, if its odd re add `<>`